# Converting Address (Street Address, City, State, Zip Code) to FIPS Code

Tags: maps, gis

I am trying to convert an address of the type:

24 Willie Mays Plaza, San Francisco, CA 94107

to a FIPS code (in this case, it would be 075).

Does anyone know any tools that can do this?  Would even be happy to pay for a service that can convert.

Comment: http://www.pb.com/software/Mailing-and-Postal-Compliance/CASS-Certification/CODE-1-Plus.shtml

Comment: araspion - I pulled the FIPS tag because its usually used with FIPS 140-2 and validated [software] modules. Please add it back if you can cite a FIPS publication or standard.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a one-time lookup here:
http://www.zipinfo.com/search/zipcode.htm

Or, you can purchase a product to use:
http://www.zip-info.com/products/products.htm